# Setting up default view path in Express.js

Tags: express, view

#### Source Code

*app.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var viewPath = path.join(__dirname, 'app/views');

app.set('views', viewPath);
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home Page' } );
});

app.listen(3000);
```

#### Folder Structure

```
app
└───views     
│        └───index.jade
└───app.js
```

#### Error in Browser

Error: Failed to lookup view `index` in views directory `d:\Users\Admin\Documents\...\project\views`

#### Question

I would like to structure my app by placing the view files in `app/views/*.jade`, but I cannot get it working so far, using `app.set('views', ...)` should work but it doesn't

`console.log(viewPath)` shows `d:\Users\Admin\Documents\...\project\app\views`

I also tried e.g. `app.set('views', 'xxx')` but the error still get stucked on the same path, it seems like `app.set()` has never been called, what's wrong here ?, please guide.

Thanks

#### Edit

It doesn't matter what I set using `app.set('views', 'xxx')` the error will always be Error: Failed to lookup view `index` in views directory `d:\Users\Admin\Documents\...\project\views` (always keep saying the same path)

I'm so sorry about `router.get('/', ...)`, My actually project's files are different, so I was making mistake here

Answer (score 10):

Try using

```js
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Your `app.js` is in your `app` folder so I think

```js
var viewPath = path.join(__dirname, 'app/views');

app.set('views', viewPath);
```

will look into `app/app/views/` instead of `app/views/` because of `__dirname`
`__dirname` is the directory in which the currently executing script resides.

Comment: My `app.js` is outside the `app` folder, thanks anyway

Comment: And you typed `router.get` instead of `app.get` or you didn't defined `router`

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late, but might help someone who has the same problem. If you placed the rendering code in a separate file, then you need to use `express.Router` instead of `app.get`. For example,

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then in your `app.js`,

```
const router = require('./app/routes/routerName');
app.use('/', router);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Roxinagi, you should be using app.get().
Everything else seems fine

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('index', { title: 'Home Page' } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually have separated files in my project, so I have `app.get('/', ...)` in the separated route file, then require it to use with `app.use()`

I really have no ideas but after moving only the `app.get('/', ...)` to the `app.js`, the problem has been solved

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app/views/'))
app.set('view engine','jade');
```

Comment: please add some explanation